# Multiple Views from Inflated Layout in horizontal ScrollView

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-scrollview

Apologies if I don't manage to get my question across properly but it's been a while since I have developed for Android.

What I am trying to do is have a number of tabs at the top of the screen which when pressed show a ScrollView. This is not something I want to use a ViewPager for as the swiping action need to be separate from the tabs.

Each ScrollView should have one child which is a LinearLayout (orientation horizontal) which should take the height of the ScrollView but the width should wrap the content contained. (The width of the content should match that of the width of the screen).

The Content Views which are Inflated inside the Fragment Activity for the tab should sit side by side, each one taking up the whole space given to the content of a tab.

Below is an illustration of what I am trying describe as well as the code snippets of the layouts created that are not working.

[image]

**Fragment Layout - (tab_fragment.xml)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView 
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/tabScrollView"
        android:fillViewport="true">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:id="@+id/pageLinearLayout"
            ></LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

**Inflated View - (article_layout.xml)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ImageView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#ff0000">
</ImageView>
```

**Fragment Activity**

```
// Inflate the layout for this fragment
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_fragment, container, false);

LinearLayout pageLinearLayout = (LinearLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.pageLinearLayout);

for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
    View pageView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.article_layout, null);
    if(i % 2 != 0){
        pageView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#00ffff"));
    }
    pageLinearLayout.addView(pageView);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

I have add a layout file named scrollmain( only include a LinearLayout) ,and I test following code and it work well:

```
 //View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_fragment, container, false);
    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.scrollmain);
    LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_fragment, null, false);
    layout.addView(view)

    LinearLayout pageLinearLayout = (LinearLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.pageLinearLayout);

    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        View pageView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.article_layout, null);
        if(i % 2 != 0){
            pageView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#00ffff"));
        }
        pageLinearLayout.addView(pageView);
    }
```

Good luck.

Comment: What do you mean by it works? I don't have an ID set called scrollmain so that is of no use to me.

Comment: No, I test code and add this layout file,it has a linearlayout only. and you have a 'container' instance, I think you can change your code to try. secondly, you can set a real background image ,not only with color